# JqGrid How to save changes on checkbox's column at once with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a column called 'asistencia' filled with data collected from a database and shown as checkboxes (I use the property `formatoptions: {disabled : false}` so they are checked beforehand depending on the data).

What I need is to have a 'save' button that will record any changes made to those chechboxes into the database.
So basically, I don't know how to do that and capting those changes. I thought about using the XML that fills the grid, but I don't figure out how. Any help is much appreciated! 
I'm a dummy with all jquery's stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem, my sln is as follows (maybe there is a better one):

1. Define global variable for grid data. `var gridData;`
2. Make sure the `loadOnce` is set to true.
3. Add `loadComplete` event to your grid and set the global variable in 1.
4. Write your own custom checkbox formatter and defined click event for it.
5. In the click event handler you can manipulate the grid data with the current value of the clicked checkbox.

Hope this help,

It seems like a bug, so I can only hope that someone out there will attend to it :)